# Pi2 has no red light

Tags: hardware

I have been working with my Pi2 for about a 10 days, it worked OK and I had no problem, today when I was working with a step motor driver, PI suddenly turn off and now it is not turning on.
Usually when you have no red light, it means that your power source has problem but in my case that's not true. I was working whit my power source for 10 days, also I testes my power source again with a B+ model which it worked fine.
Also when I plug the power source to the my Pi2, one of the very little part at the back of the board (between c94 and c49) gets hot that I can't touch it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems safe to assume that you blew something in the board.  If you're not getting any of the LEDs to turn on and it gets that hot, something somewhere is drastically wrong.

Comment: of-course, the question is what thing?

Comment: @NimaNr: my guess is the power regulator. Though I don't have a RPi in front of me, so I can't tell off the top of my head where c94/c49 is.